# get last three month records from table

Tags: postgresql, date

How to get last 3 months records from the table.

```
SELECT * 
from table 
where month > CURRENT_DATE-120 
  and month < CURRENT_DATE 
order by month;
```

I have used the above query is it correct? shall I use this for get last 3 month record from the table.

Comment: select c.id credito, p.nombres, p.apellidos from creditos c, personas p where c.solicitante=p.id and c.aprobado=true
 and c.fechaini between CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months' and  CURRENT_DATE
group by p.nombres, p.apellidos, c.id;

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use built-in `INTERVAL` instruction

Check how this works:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months'
```

and you can rewrite your SQL to:

```
SELECT * from table where date >  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months'
```

(not checked but this should give you an idea how to use INTERVAL instruction)

Comment: It should probably be noted that this approach would retrieve records which have a 'date' field that is in between the current date and "3 months" ago (which would essentially be the same as saying 28, 30, or 31 days ago, depending on the month). If you want records that have a date that lies within the last 3 calendar months, you would have to do something different.

Comment: @jstol what exactly?

Comment: I had to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get the behavior I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE month BETWEEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW() - INTERVAL '3 months')
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW())
ORDER BY month
;
```

Comment: And how do you think that is going to work come January? (It won't)

Comment: It won't I know, but the question implies it as we only know the existence of the month column and we don't know if a year exists in his relation

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```sql
select * from table
where date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months' and CURRENT_DATE
```

or

```sql
select * from table
where date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months' and date <= CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score -1):

This filters the last 3 calendar months

```
SELECT * from table where date >=  to_char(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months', 'YYYY-MM-01')::date
```

Comment: How is this better than the top voted answer?  Why would you convert to varchar then force an explicit conversion back to date?

Comment: The difference is that the top voted does not bring the calendar month, instead brings the same day 3 months before, something like 93 days before. As the coment from jstol suggest.

For example as today 2022-01-12 mine brings from 2021-10-01 and the top voted brings 2021-10-12. I tested this.

Comment: The '-01' does it very quick without needing a more soffisticated option, because the conversions in the filter is applied only to a value and not to the table.

Comment: The original author did not say previous 3 calendar months and his original code would not have produced a calendar month result, but since you did put the word "calendar" in your answer, I cede the point that it is different and potentially useful.  The computation in the top voted answer is also on the filter, not on the row value.

Comment: Yeah, the author was not really explicit in that matter. So i pointed just in case it was, because i was searching for it too, and this post apeard to me and give me the correct way to the solution. And i mentioned the computation because i thought that could be the point of your first comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
select date::date
from generate_series((current_date - INTERVAL '1 Month')::date, (current_date - INTERVAL '1 DAY')::date,'1
day'::interval) date
WHERE date >= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '3' month)
and date < date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

This will give **last three months date list**, excluding current months date. Example if current month is November.  This list will give use all dates of August, Septemeber and October.