# Get the records of last month in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the records of last month based on my db table [note] field "date_created".

What's the sql to do this?

last month - 2015-08-30 to 2015-09-30

I used below query used from link but [get last three month records from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117582/get-last-three-month-records-from-table) but getting error ORA-30089: missing or invalid

```
select *
from   note
where  to_date(DATE_CREATED)  >  to_date(CURRENT_DATE) - to_date(INTERVAL '3 months')
```

Even I used below query but still getting error : ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

```
select *
from   note 
where  to_date(DATE_CREATED) BETWEEN '2015-08-30 00:00:00.0' AND '2015-09-30 00:00:00.0'
```

Comment: And you're using SQL-Server?

Comment: This is oracle chief ORA-....

Comment: This must be the 2018 version which has ORA errors

Comment: What is the datatype of the DATE_CREATED column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using TO_DATE on the literal strings as well.

```
select * from note where to_date(DATE_CREATED) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-08-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2015-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not Oracle syntax.
If you want to use INTERVAL you can use only YEAR_TO_MONTH or DAY_TO_SECOND interval.

It will looks like this (for last 3 months):

```
select *
from   note
where  to_date(DATE_CREATED)  >  to_date(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '0-3' YEAR TO MONTH
```

Or your can use standard function ADD_MONTHS:

```
select *
from   note
where  to_date(DATE_CREATED)  > ADD_MONTHS( to_date(CURRENT_DATE), -3)
```

`ADD_MONTHS` will add months to your date. It could be positive or negative

Comment: Do not use `INTERVAL` to add or subtract months; if you subtract 3 months from 31st May then you will get 31st February which is not a valid date and Oracle will raise an exception. Just use `ADD_MONTHS`, which handles issues like that nicely.