# Filter timestamp by specific month-year

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I am new to postgres and would appreciate any advice. I have postgres table with a `timestamp` column whose values are in the format: `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

My objective is to select records from the last three whole months - December 2016, January 2017 and February 2017.  How would one write this query with only read access using `SELECT`?

When I start with:

`SELECT to_char("start_time", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') FROM trips;`

Times are converted to AM/PM but I am only interested in extracting and subsetting by month and year

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM trips
WHERE start_time BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2017-02-28 23:59:59'::timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where start_date >= date_trunc('month',now() - interval '3' month) and
      start_date < date_trunc('month', now());
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `ERROR:  column "month" does not exist
LINE 4: start_time <- date_trunc(month, now());`   There is no  month column in my table only a `start_date`

Comment: @the_darkside Use `start_date >= date_trunc('month',now()-interval '3' month)
and start_date < date_trunc('month', now());` in where condition I think this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract` or `date_trunc` function to extract month in postgresql.

Very similar to question [get last three month records from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117582/get-last-three-month-records-from-table)

For more details about date time functions in postgresql use below link.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html